# Angular/HTML - How do you restrict RegEx results to values 1-10?

Tags: html, angular, regex, forms

I am working on an exercise where we are testing form validation in an Angular template.  The restrictions for the one input field are that the selection should be a number from 1-10.

My first try was below, as I was taught using pipes could separate literals.

`pattern="[1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10]"`

When that did not work for 10, I tried the below two lines, which still did not let me include 10, but did allow 0.

`pattern="[1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|(10)]"`

`pattern="[1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|(10)]{1}"`

This is my first stackoverflow question, so I think I included enough, but I will provide more information if needed.

Comment: you are using [] as class of characters but you can't encode 10 that way ... maybe this: `(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10)`

Comment: `^(?:[1-9]|10)$`

Comment: Just to mention there are quite some online regex-for-range generators like [Regex-Range.com](https://www.regex-range.com/) might want to [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the pattern to `^` and `$` end.

Answer (score 1):

Use this RegEx: `^([1-9]|10)$`

Explanation:

`^` Assert position at start of line.

`(` Capture group open.

`[1-9]` Match a single character in the range between 1 and 9.

`|` Equivalent to logical OR.

`)` Capture group close.

`$` Assert position at the end of the line.